# How to share test classes across Gradle projects?

Tags: java, gradle

I am using Gradle to build and test my projects. I have two projects:

```
ProjA  contains      src\test\java\BaseTest.java       
ProjB  contains      src\test\java\MyTest.java

MyTest extends BaseTest
```

When I run `ProjB.gradle`, how do I get it to see the `BaseTest` class from ProjA?

I tried adding:

```
dependencies {
  testCompile project('ProjA') 
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Can you clarify "it didn't work"?  Did you get an error message?  Did your code not compile?   Did you get a NoClassDefFound message during runtime?

Answer (score 39):

Maybe there are better, simpler ways, cleaner ways, but I think you have three options here.

#### First option

Since `BaseTest` is a class that is in fact part of a reusable testing library (you use it in both projects), you could simply create a `testing` subprojects, where BaseTest is defined in src/main/java and not src/test/java. The `testCompile` configuration of the other two subprojects would both have a dependency on `project('testing')`.

#### Second option (UPDATED for Gradle 7.3)

In this second option, you would define an additional artifact and configuration in the first project:

```
configurations {
  testClasses {
    extendsFrom(testImplementation)
  }
}

task testJar(type: Jar) {
  archiveClassifier.set('test')
  from sourceSets.test.output
}

// add the jar generated by the testJar task to the testClasses dependency
artifacts {
  testClasses testJar
}
```

and you would depend on this configuration in the second project:

```
dependencies {
  testCompile project(path: ':ProjA', configuration: 'testClasses')
}
```

#### Third option

Basically the same as the second one, except it doesn't add a new configuration to the first project:

```
task testJar(type: Jar) {
  archiveClassifier.set('test')
  from sourceSets.test.output
}

artifacts {
  testRuntime testJar
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
  testCompile project(path: ':one', configuration: 'testRuntime')
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `Could not get unknown property 'testRuntime' for configuration ':projA:testClasses' of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Thanks, it still valid as today (2nd & 3rd options)

Comment: @gopalanrc I get the same error today but it's due to I'm working on a `com.android.library`. Have you resolved this ?

Comment: second option worked very good for me.

Comment: For Gradle 7+ you need to define a new configuration. So the second option is OK.

Comment: For Gradle 7+ you need to change `extendsFrom(testRuntime)` to `extendsFrom(testRuntimeOnly)`. See [link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#changes_7.0) for details.

Comment: Option #2 perfectly worked for me

Comment: **Option #2 perfectly worked for me. details are below**

**Added the below in project1**
`task testJar(type: Jar) {
  archiveClassifier.set('test')
  from sourceSets.test.output
}

artifacts {
  testRuntime testJar
}
`
**Added below in project2:**
`configurations {

    testImplementation.extendsFrom(testCompile)

}
dependencies {

testCompile project(path: ':project1', configuration: 'testClasses')

}
`