# How Do We Inherit Test Classes Across Android Library Modules?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android Studio project with two library modules: `foo-module` and `bar-module`. Each implements a library, with `foo-module` defining a strategy interface and `bar-module` depending upon `foo-module` and implementing such a strategy. `foo-module` has instrumentation tests (`foo-module/src/androidTest/`) to test its core code, using a stub strategy implementation, and `bar-module` should have its own instrumentation tests.

I defined an `AbstractTests` class in `foo-module/src/androidTest/` that does most of the actual testing. I also have a `StubTests` class in `foo-module/src/androidTest/` that extends `AbstractTests` and implements the necessary `abstract` methods to complete the test case (providing an implementation of the strategy, etc.). This all works great.

In `bar-module/src/androidTest/`, I created a `BarStrategyTests` class, designed to mirror `StubTests`, but provide the strategy implemented in `bar-module`. However, `BarStrategyTests` cannot see `AbstractTests`, even though I have `compile project(':foo-module')` in my `build.gradle` file, and the main (non-test) classes in `bar-module` can work fine with the main (non-test) classes in `foo-module`. IOW, while the `project()` dependency handles regular code, it does not handle `androidTest/` code. I get "error: package com.commonsware.foo.test does not exist".

I tried also adding `androidTestCompile project(':foo-module')`, with the same result.

What is the recipe for sharing instrumentation test code between modules?

Temporarily, I can clone `AbstractTests`, but that's not a great long-term solution.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31814812/115145) covers similar ground for ordinary Java. Has anyone tried the options in [the one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32780697/115145) and gotten them to work for Android instrumentation tests? The first option (move the common testing code into yet another module as regular non-test code) seems plausible, but I have no idea if the other two will work well with the `com.android.library` plugin instead of the `java` plugin.

Comment: did you find a way to achieve to this? I want to make my test classes available for the other modules too, but having difficulties to share the resources.

Comment: @karate: I am using the approach outlined in the accepted answer.

Comment: There should be a better way to do this instead of moving the all the test classes to their own module and extending from them :(
Someone who is responsible for gradle should make it easier for us to extend test classes

Comment: Solution for Android + Kotlin projects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63298267/12001093

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Due to the fact that all the test classes (unit and instrumentation) are not a part of any module, including aar, they are not available via dependency to that module. I faced to this issue as well and solved it by creating `test-module` and put all the required classes in it (`src/main/java`). 
So, in your case you can move `AbstractTests` in this module and use this module as a `androidTestCompile` dependency.

Comment: I can definitely see needing to do something different if I were depending upon a pre-packaged AAR, such as a repository artifact. I had expected that `compile project(':foo-module')` would match up the appropriate sourcesets -- after all, it's not `compile projectButJustTheMainSourcesetPlease(':foo-module')`. :-) I'm going to leave this open for a while to see if anyone else has another option, but I will not be shocked if yours winds up being the best option. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note that this approach seems to require multiple additional modules. Basically, `foo-module` cannot have any tests of its own. Not only does `AbstractTests` have to get moved to `foo-module-test-common`, but any tests formerly in `foo-module` have to get moved to `foo-module-test`. Otherwise, you get circular dependencies: `foo-module` has `androidTestCompile` on `foo-module-test-common`, which has `compile` on `foo-module`. `foo-module` cannot have a dependency on `foo-module-test-common` as a result. What a pain.

Comment: Well, you have to avoid `foo-module` depends on `foo-module-test-common`. One option is to move all the tests from `foo-module` to `foo-module-test-common` so this module not just contains common test-classes in `src/main/java` but also contains the tests for `foo-module` in `src/androidTest/java`.

Comment: Ah, good point. I wasn't thinking of that combination. Thanks again!

Comment: @CommonsWare were you able to come up with a proper solution for this? I'm facing a similar issue, but my "base" test utils that I want to be inherited cross-module rely on stuff from `org.junit.*` (e.g. test rules) which don't work in `main/java`...

Comment: @Droidman: That project was a few years ago, but IIRC wound up doing more or less what is here. AFAIK, a library can use `org.junit.*` classes in its `main` code -- you just need to have the JUnit dependency as a regular one (e.g., `api` or `implementation`) and not a test one (e.g., `androidTestApi` or `androidTestImplementation`).

Comment: @CommonsWare oh, thanks :) Indeed I have just copy-pasted the test dependencies from another module so it was `testImplementation`. Adding jUnit, AssertJ et al. as "real" dependencies works just fine.