# How to share instrumentation test classes from androdTest?

Tags: dependencies, android-testing

I have some instrumentation test classes under the folder androidTest which I would like to share across the other modules. The problem is when I add this module in the other project as a dependency androidTestCompile some resources are still missing. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do We Inherit Test Classes Across Android Library Modules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078710/how-do-we-inherit-test-classes-across-android-library-modules)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `sourceSets` in your modules, not sure if it will work, but worth to try out.

```
android {
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    androidTest.setRoot('tests')
}}
```